# esp32 arduino mqtt over websocket?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, esp32

I'm working on something that needs MQTT over websocket (my server limitation on port 80)

I've looked everywhere for it, but either no one have ability to !ratain or (||) send over websocket packets. :D

I've somehow get to this include in arduino ---> its close src and low language (at least for me!)

```
#include "mqtt_client.h"
```

and does this on my code:

```
 esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqttConfig;
  mqttConfig.uri = "ws://test.mosquitto.org";
  mqttConfig.port = 8080;
  mqttConfig.transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_WS;
  mqttConfig.event_handle(evt);
  esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqttConfig);
  //esp_mqtt_client_register_event(client, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, mqtt_event_handler, client);
  esp_mqtt_client_start(client);
```

ERROR:

```
cannot convert 'void (*)(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t) {aka void (*)(esp_mqtt_event_t*)}' to 'esp_mqtt_event_handle_t {aka esp_mqtt_event_t*}' in argument passing
```

I'll send the header file below and some more:

[arduino_H file](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/mqtt/mqtt_client.h)

Comment: What do you mean by "server limitation on port 80"? test.mosquitto.org doesn't require you to use websockets and the code you shared isn't trying to connect to port 80. MQTT over web sockets is primarily for use from Javascript in a browser. Why do you think you have to run MQTT over web sockets on an ESP32?

Comment: my broker is online and its only over websocket
im using "liara.ir" thats a cheap and secure " mqtt server provider "

Comment: in this demo i want to connect ws mqtt specifically

Answer (score 0):

Here:
`esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqttConfig);` you are not giving the function handle, but... assigning the result of invoked function...

This should be:
`esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = esp_mqtt_client_init;`